# Movie data set with demographic information of users

Tags: demographics, film

I am doing movie popularity prediction using Long Short Term Memory networks model.

I am testing with MovieLens dataset with 100K and 1M ratings, which include demographic information of users. Below are the links of two datasets:

MovieLens 100K: https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/100k/

MovieLens 1M: https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/1m/

I am doing with these datasets because I would like to leverage demographic information of users (e.g., age, gender) for my model.

However, these datasets just collected data within a short period of time. Specifically, for the first dataset, it was collected during the seven-month period from September 19th, 1997 through April 22nd, 1998. For the second one, from 2000-2003, but almost data gathered in the first year.

Therefore any other movie datasets with user demographic information collected in a longer period of time will be appreciated. Thank you very much for your help.